# MYSQL query in Wordpress without a specific meta_key in wp_usermeta

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

I am trying to write a MYSQL in Wordpress query to search for users without a specific meta_key in wp_usermeta for the moment I write the opposite: users with a specified meta_key.

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_usermeta.meta_key, wp_usermeta.meta_value 
FROM `wp_users` LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta
ON  wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id AND (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nombre_curso' OR             wp_usermeta.meta_key ='caduca_enlace1')
```

How can I rewrite this to obtain only wp_users.ID WITHOUT specified meta_key rows?
Thanks

Comment: Hi. You should look at the meta query for wp user query. 'meta_compare'
(string) Comparison operator to test the $meta_value. Accepts '=', '!=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN', 'EXISTS', 'NOT EXISTS', 'REGEXP', 'NOT REGEXP', or 'RLIKE'. Default '='.

Comment: Possible solution for future reference: SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_email FROM `wp_users` 
WHERE wp_users.ID NOT IN (
 SELECT wp_usermeta.user_id 
    FROM wp_usermeta 
    WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'caduca_enlace1'

Answer (score 0):

A first solution
        SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_email FROM `wp_users` 
        WHERE wp_users.ID NOT IN (
            SELECT wp_usermeta.user_id 
            FROM wp_usermeta 
            WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'caduca_enlace1' )

Thanks @Howard E.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't use the wp_user_query class

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_email
    FROM  wp_users
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
             FROM  wp_usermeta
             WHERE meta_key = 'caduca_enlace1' 
               AND user_id = wp_users.ID )
```